# Multi-language / Multi-brand Salesforce Communities

Tags: community, customer-portal, community-builder

We are looking at implementing a customer facing application using Salesforce communities, and in the simple case this looks very straightforward.

However, it's always the way that a couple of requirements seem to cause us some difficulties.

- We operate as multiple brands.  We'd like to present the same application branded in multiple ways, but manage a single code-base / configuration.  This should include:

  - The look of the site / colours / images, etc.
  - The look any notification emails (new user / chatter notifications / etc).
  - The URL to be different for each brand.
- We operate in multiple languages, and so would like content to be language specific:

  - The content of the site, labels, drop-downs, etc.
  - The content of any notification emails.

Does anyone have any experience with the above - it does not appear to be a trivial implementation, particularly when thinking about the emails.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Napili Template ? I'll try my best to give you some elements as I faced similar questions for 13 brands, meaning 13 different logos.

The look of the site / colours / images -->

- For the look & feel you can use the CSS to hide elements, change the colours
  the logos you would like to use in the banner.  You can access the
  CSS from the Brand section in the community builder.
- You can also add a new template if you want to change the component of your page, the header and footer.
- For more complex and dynamic element you might need to develop the right components

The look any notification emails (new user / chatter notifications / etc).
The URL to be different for each brand. --> 
it is more complicated. What represent the brands ? Each brand = 1 language ?

We operate in multiple languages, and so would like content to be language specific: The content of the site, labels, drop-downs, etc. -->

- Use the builder and add languages via the admin section, add language picker into your community , then select (still in the builder) the language and go to each component that needs to be translated (for topics and salesforce fields you might need to use the translation workbench too). Then repeat it for each languages.
- If you need to display different component depending on the brand you might need the use of page variations that display according to criteria such as the location, record type or profile

The content of any notification emails --> no xp on it but are we speaking of the welcome email notif of others ? is it private community?

Comment: Thanks for the update on this old question.  We came to the conclusion that the only way to realistically deal with the multi-brand problem was to manually build a community site per brand.  Not ideal, but it works.